# update this.model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update the model and view using data fetched from ajax.

using $scope (this works):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="a in arr">{{a}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

 var app = angular.module("app", [])
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http)
 {
     $scope.arr = [];
     $http.get("/angular/ajax").success(function(data){
         $scope.arr = JSON.parse(data);
     });
 });
```

but when I try with 'controller as' it doesn't

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as mc">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="a in mc.arr">{{a}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

var app = angular.module("app", [])
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope,$http) {
    this.arr = [];
    $http.get("/angular/ajax").success(function(data){
        this.arr = JSON.parse(data);
    });
});
```

P.S. beginner in angularjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is going not going to refer to the correct scope inside of your success function. In order to get it working you need to store `this` inside of a variable so you can use it inside of other functions.

```
var vm = this;  // view model
vm.arr = [];
...
vm.arr = JSON.parse(data);
```

And you would use the same template logic.

Comment: thanks for the answer, double thanks for quick reply.....SO is making me wait for 8 mins before I select your answer...

Comment: No worries. `this` has some weird properties and isn't very intuitive. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this explains the details pretty well.